# Custom nested actuator endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.0, I was able to customize the actuator endpoints as follows...

```
endpoints.beans.id=foo/springbeans
```

This would expose the spring beans endpoint at /foo/springbeans.  However, in the latest Spring Boot this is not possible due to the following code in the **AbstractEndpoint**...

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "\\w+", message = "ID must only contains letters, numbers and '_'")
private String id;
```

I tried using the underscore, but that just exposes the endpoint at **/foo_springbeans**.  This lead me to try to add a view controller so I could at least redirect or forward to the default endpoint, but I couldn't find an easy way to do that either.  How can I configure the endpoint or a redirect?

Comment: Will management.context-path property be of use? In that case all endpoints will be exposed under different path.

Comment: Another thought, does BeanPostProcessor sound like a solution? I checked and it can do the work. But I am not sure if this is desired way. In postProcessAfterInitialization for bean of BeansEndpoint setting and id to "foo/springbeans" solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but neither are what I'm looking for.  I have a business requirement to move one of the actuators and the location would not make sense for the others if I moved the entire management context.  A BeanPostProcessor is not the answer I'm looking for.  I was hoping one of the Spring devs would have an answer why this feature was removed.  Looks like I might need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening an issue with Spring Boot and being told to simply move the entire management context as suggested by Rafal, I was able to achieve what I was looking for, albeit with more code than I'd like.  I created a custom **MvcEndpoint** as follows...

```
@Named
public class MyCustomHealthCheck extends EndpointMvcAdapter {
    private HealthEndpoint delegate;

    @Inject
    public MyCustomHealthCheck(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
        super(delegate);
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/springbeans", method = GET)
    public Health foo() {
        return delegate.invoke();
    }
}
```

The code above creates the /springbeans path underwhatever path the HealthEndpoint is mapped to, which is fine enough for my usecase.  If I wanted it mapped to an entirely separate path, I would have needed to create a dummy endpoint and stick this MvcEndpoint under that.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring `1.x` Following property should help you:

```
endpoints.beans.path: /foo/springbeans
```

You can use it with any standard endpoint and if you want to use it with custom endpoint that extends `AbstractEndpoint` then you need additional annotation:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoints.customEndpoint")
```

and then use property:

endpoints.customEndpoint.path: /custom/endpoint